# OutOfMemory Exception on Android

Tags: android, exception, out-of-memory

I'm currently facing a problem where user upload a smaller size image, there will be no problem. However, when the user chooses to upload a bigger size image, the application will throw OutOfMemory exception.

Should I set an image size limit that can be uploaded?

Comment: Please provide some code. As per my thinking you need to compress the size programatically.

Comment: provide some code and be more concrete

Comment: Frankly, quite difficult to help. May be the image size exceeds the size of the `heap`. Did you check the size of the heap?

Comment: Do you use a mobile phone to check or an emulator?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to upload the image, there is no need to hold the whole image in memory. Instead you should use streams to upload it.
If you also want to display the image (for selection or whatever) consider using a thumbnail.